# Supplied parameter error when using a mixin in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to learn Typescript and was playing with the mixin idea.  I have the following code, which is silly, but it's practice.  Also, it works when I run it.  But the line 42, `myInput.sendKeys(name);`, states "Supplied parameters do not match signature of target." But I'm not sure what I need to change to fix it.

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}

class SendKeys {
    inputEl;

    sendKeys(data: string) {
        this.inputEl.value = data;
    }
}

class InputClass implements SendKeys {
    inputEl: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor() {
    }

    sendKeys: () => void;

    createInput(name: string) {
        this.inputEl = document.createElement('input');
        this.inputEl.type = 'text';
        this.inputEl.setAttribute('id', name);
        document.body.appendChild(this.inputEl);
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
applyMixins(InputClass, [SendKeys])


let myInput = new InputClass();

let nameArr = ["frank", "Joe", "Laryy"];

for (let name of nameArr) {
    myInput.createInput(name);
    myInput.sendKeys(name);
}
```

[See the code in action here](http://function%20applyMixins(derivedCtor:%20any,%20baseCtors:%20any[])%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20derivedCtor.prototype[name]%20=%20baseCtor.prototype[name];%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR; fix the signature of `sendKeys` in `InputClass` to:

```
 sendKeys: (data: string) => void;
```

The `applyMixin` method is executed at runtime.

At compile time, there is no way that the Typescript compiler knows that your you are going to mix class `SenKeys` into class `InputClass` and by doing so change the signature of the `sendKeys` method from a parameter less, to a single parameter method.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing `SendKeys` incorrectly, it should be:

```
sendKeys: (data: string) => void;
```

Like this:

```
class InputClass implements SendKeys {
    inputEl: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor() {}

    sendKeys: (data: string) => void;

    createInput(name: string) {
        this.inputEl = document.createElement('input');
        this.inputEl.type = 'text';
        this.inputEl.setAttribute('id', name);
        document.body.appendChild(this.inputEl);
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20applyMixins(derivedCtor%3A%20any%2C%20baseCtors%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20derivedCtor.prototype%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20baseCtor.prototype%5Bname%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20SendKeys%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20inputEl%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20sendKeys(data%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.inputEl.value%20%3D%20data%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20InputClass%20implements%20SendKeys%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20inputEl%3A%20HTMLInputElement%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20sendKeys%3A%20(data%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20createInput(name%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.inputEl%20%3D%20document.createElement('input')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.inputEl.type%20%3D%20'text'%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.inputEl.setAttribute('id'%2C%20name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(this.inputEl)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AapplyMixins(InputClass%2C%20%5BSendKeys%5D)%0A%0A%0Alet%20myInput%20%3D%20new%20InputClass()%3B%0A%0Alet%20nameArr%20%3D%20%5B%22frank%22%2C%20%22Joe%22%2C%20%22Laryy%22%5D%3B%0A%0Afor%20(let%20name%20of%20nameArr)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20myInput.createInput(name)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20myInput.sendKeys(name)%3B%0A%7D))

And then the error goes away.